# Update categorical levels in bokeh patch chart

Tags: python, bokeh

Building off of the example provided on bokeh website gallery, I added a dropdown widget. The dropdown values map to different lists of categorical levels.
What I'd like the update_data_plot function to do is to update those levels and diplay the new distributions.

```
from numpy import linspace
from scipy.stats.kde import gaussian_kde

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FixedTicker, PrintfTickFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.perceptions import probly
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox, column
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, TextInput, Dropdown

# widgets
menu = [('A','A'), ('B','B')]
dropdown = Dropdown(label="Dropdown button", button_type="warning", menu=menu)


def ridge(category, data, scale=20):
    return list(zip([category]*len(data), scale*data))

def update_data_plot(attrname, old, new):
    """Update the chart to show
    the new categorical levels and
    their distribution"""

cats1 = list(reversed(probly.keys()))[:5]
cats2 = list(reversed(probly.keys()))[5:]


x = linspace(-20,110, 500)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x))

p = figure(y_range=cats1, plot_width=900, x_range=(-5, 105), toolbar_location=None)

for i, cat in enumerate(reversed(cats1)):
    pdf = gaussian_kde(probly[cat])
    y = ridge(cat, pdf(x))
    source.add(y, cat)
    p.patch('x', cat, alpha=0.6, line_color="black", source=source)

p.outline_line_color = None
p.background_fill_color = "#efefef"

p.xaxis.ticker = FixedTicker(ticks=list(range(0, 101, 10)))
p.xaxis.formatter = PrintfTickFormatter(format="%d%%")

p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = "#dddddd"
p.xgrid.ticker = p.xaxis[0].ticker

p.axis.minor_tick_line_color = None
p.axis.major_tick_line_color = None
p.axis.axis_line_color = None

p.y_range.range_padding = 0.12

dropdown.on_change('value',update_data)


curdoc().add_root(column(dropdown,
    p, width=50))
curdoc().title = "Sliders"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I did something like this. I did this on a local bokeh serve application, I don't think I ever got it working in a notebook. Looking at my old code, updating the `source.data` with the `.data` of a new `ColumnDataSource` worked.

```
def update_data_plot(attrname, old, new):
    new_value = dropdown.value
    # here make something that you can pass to construct a new ColumnDatasource with the new value
    # and put it into a variable called newdata
    source.data = ColumnDataSource(data=newdata).data
```